# How to make an update method in singly linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to make an update (replace) method in my linked list.. I've done add, search and delete methods but now I don't know how to make a method that will replace specific data in a node for example the date or room. I want the user to search for a code and then be able to edit the information of that specific node.

Here is my program :

```
public class myNodes {

public String name,department,code;
public Object date,time;
    public myNodes next;
    public int room;

    public myNodes(String name,String department,String code,Object date,Object time,int room)
    {
        this(name,department,code,date,time,room,null);
    }
    public myNodes (String name,String department,String code,Object date,Object time,int room,myNodes n)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.department=department;
        this.code=code;
        this.date=date;
        this.time=time;
        this.room=room;
        next=n;
    }
```

---

```
class MyList1 {


    protected myNodes head,tail;
    public MyList1()
    {
        head=tail=null;
    }

    public void addToHead(String name,String department,String code,Object date,Object time,int room)
    {
        head=new myNodes (name,department,code,date,time,room,head);
        if(tail == null)
            tail=head;
    }


    public String deleteFromHead()
    {
        String e1=head.name+head.department+head.code+head.date+head.time+head.room;
        if(head==tail)
            head=tail=null;
        else
            head=head.next;
        return e1;
    }


    public void printAll()
    {

        if(head!=null)
        {
            for(myNodes tmp=head;tmp!=null;tmp=tmp.next)
            System.out.println (tmp.name+"\t"+tmp.department+"\t"+tmp.code+"\t"+tmp.date+"\t"+tmp.time+"\t"+tmp.room+"\n");
        }

        else
            System.out.println("The list is empty");

    }


    //Search by code
    public boolean Search(String e1)
    {
        myNodes tmp;
        for(tmp=head;tmp!=null && !tmp.code.equals(e1); tmp=tmp.next);
        return tmp!=null;
    }



    //delete by code 
    public void delete(String e1)
    {
        if(head != null)
        {
            if(head == tail && e1.equalsIgnoreCase(head.code))
                head=tail=null;
            else if (e1 == head.code)
                head=head.next;
            else
            {
                myNodes pred,tmp;
                for(pred=head,tmp=head.next; tmp!=null && tmp.code.equalsIgnoreCase(e1);
                    pred=pred.next,tmp=tmp.next);

                if (tmp!=null)
                    pred.next=tmp.next;
                if(tmp==tail)
                    tail=pred;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

UPDATE:

Here I added a return type for the print method .. it works but when I update an info it doesn't print that node.. any help?

```
public String printAll()
{
    String s = "";

        for(myNodes tmp=head;tmp!=null;tmp=tmp.next)
          return tmp.toString();


return s;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first recommend that the search by name would be a different function, and both delete and update use that, thus making it more maintainable and easier to understand.

Second, If you're trying to implement a singly-linked list, you shouldn't be worrying about tail.

Try something like this:

```
public boolean editNode(String searchValue, String newValue)
{
    boolean success = False;
    myNodes tmp = searchByCode(searchValue);
    if (tmp != Null) //It would be better to use exceptions
    {
        tmp.setName(newValue); //I'm assuming you have getters and setters. and of course you could do anything else in here
        success = True;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Where searchByName is a function that takes a search argument (you can overload it to take one, many or all attributes of the node) and returns the Node itself or null(the null part not a necessity, just to make it work with the specific function above.
Also as commented above, it would be better to use exceptions but just in case I assumed you don't use those yet.

the searchByCode function could do something like:

```
public myNodes searchByCode(String e1) //Assuming you have a single occurrence of code in your list, otherwise, it returns the last occurrence
{
    myNodes tmp, retVal = null;
    for(tmp=head; tmp!=null; tmp=tmp.next)
    {
      if (e1.equalsIgnoreCase(tmp.getCode()))
        {
            retVal = tmp;
        }
    }
    return retVal
}
```

for your update change to this:

```
public String printAll()
{
    String s = "";

        for(myNodes tmp=head;tmp!=null;tmp=tmp.next)
          s += tmp.toString();


return s;
}
```

Comment: umm.. Is it possible to help me with one last thing? it's the print method.. I need to make it into a return type method but when I do it only prints the last value. I want it to print all the list. Sorry if I sound really dumb I'm just sort of new to this

Comment: What do you want it to return? an array or only one value? are you going to implement the for outside of the print method?

Comment: I want to print the values to a JTextArea in another class so I need to make it a String return type and I want to print the whole list not just a value

Comment: Well i would make a toString() @Override in the Node class, and then print all would just use a for to iterate the list appending each string with the necessary format you need to return. Hope this makes sense

Comment: I'm so sorry but it doesn't make sense to me.. so the print method will not be a return type?

Comment: You would have a `printAll()` method that would return a String, depending on how you need to format that string you can concatenate each iteration of the loop. In the `printAll()` you call the for going from the beginning of the list to the end, and each node calling a println (therefore using it's `toString()` method). and in the Node class you need to override the `toString()` method inherited from Object (make a new method) printing it similarly to what you have `System.out.println (this.name+"\t"+this.department+"\t"+this.code+"\t"+this.date+"\t"+this.time+"\t"+this.room+"\n")`

Comment: I updated my question.. if you can please have a look and thank you so much for your help !!

Comment: updated answer, a bit clunky, but you should be able to figure it out from there